# Teracopy not being used as handler for copying files onto phone's storage

Tags: windows-7, teracopy

I am running Teracopy on Windows 7-64bit. It works perfectly in all conditions other than when I am copying from/to my phone's storage. In this case, [the default copier is being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u1pY.png). The default copier is, as expected, unbearably slow.

So, how can I set Teracopy as a default for copying files from/to my phone? (Teracopy is already set to default and is working in all other directories.)

Comment: Close voter: phones are off-topic except when the question is about interfacing it with a computer, which is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Teracopy will **NOT** paste to Android under File Transfer Mode - took a while to figure out that this just will not work

All Androids are not created equal so I had to figure this by trial and error

MotoZ4 phone did not have MTP mode option but did have a PTP option

So you use an available folder (DCIM or Pictures) as a temporary destination folder (or create a sub-folder) for the PTP operation

Use Windows copy (or cut) and paste commands - Teracopy options will not be invoked.

This example is specifically to copy/move music files from a PC to the Music folder on a phone using PTP mode since MTP mode was not available on this phone.

The principles of this process should work for copying/moving files of any type from a PC folder to any folder on an android

**- on phone**
- select USB mode to PTP (Photo Transfer Protocol)

**- on PC**
- select MotoZ4 > Internal shared storage > then either DCIM or Pictures
as a destination folder
- go to copy (or move) source and select items to be copied (or moved)
- go to destination folder (DCIM or Pictures) [create a sub-directory if
needed to isolate the copied/moved files]
- paste item(s) to destination folder

**- on Phone**
- change USB mode to File Transfer

**- on PC**
- select MotoZ4 > Internal shared storage > select either DCIM or Pictures
(then, wherever you pasted the music temporarily)
- in this source folder select items to be moved (I assume you'd want to
move (not copy) them) to destination Music folder
- go to destination Music folder
- paste item(s) to be moved

```
 - [optional] go to the temporary source folder and delete any temporary 
   sub-folder(s) you may have created

 - unplug the USB cable and you’re done
```

This worked for me on Win10 and Win11 - probably will work for Win7 too

Thanks for reading,
LUAP

Answer (score -1):

If you are transferring data from your phone through ***MTP/PTP***, then your default copier will be used.

**Android Phones:** Instead connect your phone in **Mass Storage** mode (in USB mode selection screen or Menu -> Settings -> Storage -> USB Mode or Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Settings for older android phones) to use TeraCopy.

On a **Windows Phone**, you just can't change the USB Connection Mode. So, no TeraCopy.

Comment: Can't find the option "USB Mode or Menu" under "Storage" in Android 7.0

Comment: @MarcoLackovic Menu means the menu key a.k.a triple dot

Comment: there is no menu key nor triple dots in Settings/Storage, in Android 7.0